# CSS let floats fill unused space

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a little css float problem.

I have 3 floating div's. As viewed below

```
<div style="width : 200px;">
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 50px; ">div 1</div>
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 90px; ">div 2</div>
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 50px; ">div 3</div>
</div>
```

What I want is that div number 3 is floating up in the empty space below div 1.

Is that possible with css?

Comment: looks like its already floating under div 1

Comment: It's working here in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/EPsGn/ atleast how I understood.

Comment: How do you want to show ? can you Show me a screen-shot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

float your div 2 to the right not left.

And write your css properly, not as style in the div

http://jsfiddle.net/feqJT/1

```
.b{float : right; width : 90px; height : 90px;}
```

You can then get rid of space by changing the size of the holding div, or add padding-right:20px; or margin-right:20px; depending what you want.  Difference between padding and margin for a different post.

```
.b{float : right; width : 90px; height : 90px; margin-right:20px;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet

```
<div style="width : 200px;">
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 50px; background-color: blue; ">div 1</div>
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 90px;background-color: red; ">div 2</div>
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 50px;background-color: green; margin-top:-40px; ">div 3</div>
</div>
```

The below code will also do the same.

```
<div style="width : 200px;">
   <div style="float : left; width : 50px; height : 50px; background-color: blue; ">div 1</div>
   <div style="float : left; width : 90px; height : 90px;background-color: red;float:right; margin-right:60px;">div 2</div>
   <div style="float : left; width : 50px; height : 50px;background-color:green; ">div 3</div>
</div>
```

Back ground color is added to see the divs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is wrapping `div 1` and `div 3` on a `<div>` then floating that to left. Like the following code:

```
<div style="width : 200px;">
   <div style="float: left;">
      <div style="width: 90px; height: 50px;">div 1</div>
      <div style="width: 90px; height: 50px;">div 3</div>
   </div>
   <div style="float: left; width: 90px; height: 90px;">div 2</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RhCQk/)**